# Rebus SqlServerTransportOptions

Tags: rebus

If you try to Configure SQL Server Transport in Rebus you are encountered with a warning that using a connection string is obsolete and you are directed to use SqlServerTransportOptions.

However I have tried to find any example or code snippet that shows how to do configuration using SqlServerTransportOptions without any success.
Kindly if any body can share a snippet on how to do it properly.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```cs
Configure.With(activator)
    .Transport(t =>
    {
        var options = new SqlServerTransportOptions(connectionString);

        t.UseSqlServer(options, queueName);
    })
    .Start();
```

? (where `connectionString` is your connection string, and `queueName` is the name of the input queue)

Generally, it should be possible with Rebus to figure things out simply by letting Intellisense and the help tooltips guide you... if it didn't work out for you in this case, I'm very curious to hear what you think is missing.